# React Select buggy in CEF v92

Tags: reactjs, select, chromium-embedded

i have a problem with selects on react in a CEF env.
Once I open a select all other selects are also open.
It will also happen if the selects has a key or an unique identifier

Does anyone know this bug? And know to fix it?

```
public render(): JSX.Element {
    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <select className={"float-right"}>
                        <option>A</option>
                        <option>B</option>
                        <option>C</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <select>
                        <option>A</option>
                        <option>B</option>
                        <option>C</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
```

[image: Open once Select open a other Select]

Comment: I may be in the minority, but I don't have a clue what CEF is, so to help get better visibility from those qualified to help, you may want to add appropriate tags to your question. From a purely React standpoint, nothing seems wrong here.

Comment: Thank you, I added a CEF tag :) Its the Chromium Embedded Framework

Comment: Also its working fine in normal chrome. Once I use the CEF env. its not working